# I got 2 views and sometimes the second one has to use content that is already present in the first one and vice-versa. How to get that content?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 2 very similar views that are rendered when a user views the following URLs:

```
www.example.com/admin/categories
www.example.com/admin/users
```

First view:

```
<div class="admin-tabs">
    <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='categories'>Categories</p>
    <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='users'>Users</p>
</div>
<div class="admin-container">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <p>$category->name</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Second view:

```
<div class="admin-tabs">
    <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='categories'>Categories</p>
    <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='users'>Users</p>
</div>
<div class="admin-container">
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <p>$user->username</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I've successfully implemented an AJAX call that triggers when the admin clicks any of the `<p>` elements with `admin-tab` class. This AJAX call determines which `<p>` element has been clicked based on the data-tab and updates the HTML content of the div with a class of `admin-container`.

This is what I can't figure out:

If I am on URL `www.example.com/admin/categories`, I want to update the admin-container div with what is inside the admin-container div of the second view.

Vice-versa, if I'm on URL `www.example.com/admin/users`, I want to update the admin-container div with what is inside the admin-container div of the first image.

I could do that by creating 2 views which contain:

First view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <p>$category->name</p>
@endforeach
```

Second view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <p>$user->username</p>
@endforeach
```

And then just return one of those 2 views, however, this way I'd be creating extra views with repeating code which I already have somewhere else. Is there any way to avoid this by getting the code from the already existing views?

Comment: One idea is to move the rendering of the HTML into each of those classes.  Then you can normalize your template (use 1 file) and have a call to return the `<p>` tags, right then it's a simple matter of swapping the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in categories (url) maybe you know in the controller it's categories.
So if it's a route parameter you can use dynamic view. I guest you have:

```
Route::get('/admin/{slug}','MyController@myFunction');
```

So in your controller you will have

```
 function myFunction (Request $request, $slug) {
    if($slug == 'categories'){
       $categories = []; //get categories
       return view('categories',compact('categories'));
    }
    if($slug == 'uesrs'){
       $users = []; get users
       return view('users',compact('users'));
    }
 }
```

other way that you can use is call by ajax and get directly the html rende and replace the content your #admin-container

Try it and let me know how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to move the generating of the `<p>` content into a class.

It looks like you have arrays with objects in them.  What I would suggest is making a container class (you can make it work like an array) the point of it is to have a `render` method that can output the `<p>` content. It can act like an array for your collection of objects, with interface ArrayAccess.

If you can do that, then your templates become this:

```
<div class="admin-tabs">
   <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='categories'>Categories</p>
   <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='users'>Users</p>
</div>
<div class="admin-container">
    $categories->render()
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="admin-tabs">
   <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='categories'>Categories</p>
   <p class='admin-tab' data-tab='users'>Users</p>
</div>
<div class="admin-container">
    $users->render()
</div>
```

Now it should be pretty clear why I wanted to do that. But if not, then as you can see the templates are almost identical.  You could replace `$user` and `$categories` with `$obj` and they would be.

So now by changing what container the view uses you can control what is output. It's not unreasonable for a class to control it's output.

Hope that helps